# Dynamic eigen declaration types using templates

Tags: c++, templates, alias, eigen

I am writing a simple program to define systems that has vectors representing the states. I would like to have a declaration type of the vector of Eigen depending on the number of states in the derived class.

I tried to achieve this using templates on aliases, something like the code shown below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using  namespace std;
using  namespace Eigen;

class A
{
public:
    template <int T>
    using StateVector = typename Matrix<double, T, 1>;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int NUM_STATES = 5;
    B(){
        StateVector<NUM_STATES> a;
        a.setIdentity();
        cout<<a<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    B b;
}
```

I ultimately want to have a type that can be used in the derived classes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

With two minor changes, your code works fine.

First, there must be no `typename` keyword here:

```
template <int T>
using StateVector = Matrix<double, T, 1>;
```

Second, `NUM_STATES` must be a compile-time constant, i.e., either declare it as element of an `enum` or as `static const int` (or `static constexpr int`, if you prefer):

```
static const int NUM_STATES = 5;
```

Full working example on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/_T0gix